# UDP between 3G connected device and WiFi PC

Tags: android, networking, basic4android

Is it possible to use UDP over the 3G network? I have tried but failed, I have an application on my PC that reads UDP packets and I'm trying to send UDP packets to that "server" using my 3G connected phone.

These scenarios works:
Local to Local over Wifi
External to External over Wifi

This does not work:
3G to PC

Comment: Are you using a public IP-Adress for your server? Maybe the ports used are closed in your routers?

Comment: Ports are forwarded on the router that the PC is behind, I can receive and send packets between my PC and a PC on another network. Same is when I have my phone on another Wifi network, it can communicate with my PC. But when I have my phone on the 3G network it does not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-dis/forums/forum/683284/topic/4058262). The most important thing for me is:

> - an iPhone can send UDP packets to hosts off the AT&T network
> - an iPhone can't receive UDP packets sent to it from a host off the AT&T NAT network
> - an iPhone SHOULD be able to send & receive UDP packets to other iPhones on the AT&T network.
> - We should be able to send DIS from an iPhone to a server
> - We should be able to do multicast on a WiFi interface, and send & receive to other
>     hosts on the same WiFi network

This should also apply to all other smartphones. If you can not receive UDP packages from your phone the packets could be blocked by your Network Provider, or something in your setup is wrong.

The bigger problems seems to me that you are unable to send data back to your phone. That makes all UDP calls a one way route and maybe render your server useless.